# Blackjack str iteration error

Tags: python, blackjack

I am converting an array into a string to print, but the compiler still says not iterable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 157, in <module>
  File "python", line 56, in total
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The function `total()` is located on line 56, if you think it is the problem, but if you run the script, you should find that the function works properly every other instance.

```
import random
import time 

def makeDeck():
  cards = []
  num = 1
  for card in range(52):
    cards.append(num)
    num += 1
    if num == 13:
      num = 1
  return cards

#def shuffle(cards):
  #for card in cards:
   #num = random.randint(0,51)
    #cards.insert(0, cards[num])
  #return cards

def shuffle(deck):
  for card in deck:
    hold = deck.pop(0)
    deck.insert(random.randint(1,51),hold)
  return deck

def cardToString(hand):
  cardString = []  
  for card in hand:
    if card == 1:
      cardString.append('Ace')
    elif card == 11:
      cardString.append('Jack')
    elif card == 12:
      cardString.append('Queen')
    elif card == 13:
      cardString.append('King')
    else:
      cardString.append(str(card))
  for card in cardString:
    return card

def deal(user,deck):
  hand = []
  for x in range(2):
    hand.append(deck.pop(0))
  return hand

def deal1(user,deck):
  hand = []
  for card in deck:
    hand.append(deck.pop(0))
  return hand

def total(hand):
  score = 0
  for card in hand:
    if(card>10):
      score += 10
    elif(card != 1):
      score += card
    else:
      if(score>=11):
        score+=1
      else:
        score+=11
  return score

#def playGame():
  #to do

name1 = input('Player 1, please enter your name:\n')
p2q = input('Will there be two plaers? (y/n)')

if(p2q == 'y' or p2q == 'Y' ):
  p2yn = 1
  name2 = input('Player 2, please enter your name:\n')
elif(p2q == 'n' or p2q == 'N'):
  p2yn = 0

deck = makeDeck()
shuffle(deck)
p1hand = deal(name1,deck)
if(p2yn == 1):
  p2hand = deal(name2,deck)
else:
  print(end = ' ')
hs=0

print(str(name1)+', your hand is:', end = ' ' )
cardToString(p1hand)
print(str(p1hand[0])+',',p1hand[1], end = ' ')
print('and your total is', total(p1hand))
time.sleep(2)
tot1 = total(p1hand)
while(tot1 < 21):
  p1cvar = input('Would you like another card? (y/n)\n')
  if(p1cvar =='n' or p1cvar == 'N'):
    break
  else:
    p1hand.append(deck.pop(0))
    newCard = str(p1hand[-1])
    cardToString(newCard)
    print('You got a', newCard)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Your total is now', total(p1hand))
    time.sleep(1)
    if(total(p1hand) <= 21):
      hs = total(p1hand)
    else:
      print('You went over 21!')
      p1hand=0
      time.sleep(1)
      break
if(p1hand != 0):
  print('The high score is', total(p1hand), 'held by', str(name1)+'.')
  time.sleep(1)
shuffle(deck)

if(p2yn == 1):
  print(str(name2)+', your hand is:', end = ' ' )
  cardToString(p2hand)
  print(str(p2hand[0])+',',p2hand[1], end = ' ')
  print('and your total is', total(p2hand))
  time.sleep(2)
  tot1 = total(p2hand)
  while(tot1 < 21):
    p2cvar = input('Would you like another card? (y/n)\n')
    if(p2cvar =='n' or p2cvar == 'N'):
      break
    else:
      p2hand.append(deck.pop(0))
      newCard = str(p2hand[-1])
      cardToString(newCard)
      print('You got a', newCard)
      time.sleep(1)
      print('Your total is now', total(p2hand))
      time.sleep(1)
      if(total(p2hand)>21):
        print('You went over 21!')
        p2hand=0
        time.sleep(1)
        break
  if(p2hand != 0 and total(p2hand)>hs):
    print('The high score is', total(p2hand), 'held by', str(name2)+'.')
    hs = total(p2hand)
  time.sleep(1)

dealerHand = deal('Dealer',deck)

print("The dealer's hand is:", end = ' ' )
cardToString(dealerHand)
print(str(dealerHand[0])+',',dealerHand[1], end = ' ')
print('and their total is', total(dealerHand))
time.sleep(2)
totD = total(dealerHand)
while(totD < 21):
  tdh = total(dealerHand)
  if(tdh<hs and tdh<22):
    dealerHand.append(deck.pop(0))
    newCard = str(dealerHand[-1])
    cardToString(newCard)
    print('Dealer got a', newCard)
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("Dealer's total is now", total(dealerHand))
    time.sleep(1)
    if(total(dealerHand) <= 21 and total(dealerHand)>hs):
      hs = total(dealerHand)
    else:
      print('Dealer went over 21!')
      dealerHand=0
  else:
    break
if(dealerHand != 0):
  print('The high score is', total(dealerHand), 'held by', str("Dealer")+'.')

while(total(p1hand)>21 or total(dealerHand)>21):
  if(total(dealerHand)>21):
    print('Dealer has been eliminated from play!')
  elif(total(p1hand)>21):
    print(name1,'has been eliminated from play!')
```

Comment: You need to reduce this down to a [mcve], and include the full error. This is far too much code to have people nearly blindly go through.

Comment: Compilation was implied

Comment: And that means that apparently in `total`, `hand` is a number, not something that's iterable. You'll need to debug to find out why.

Comment: It might be worth bearing https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ in mind while you're creating that reduced example, too.

Comment: Think about this line: `if(p2hand != 0 and total(p2hand)>hs):`. That should raise red flags. `total` expects a list, but you're checking if the hand isn't 0? If you're storing multiple types in a single variable, be ready for tears.

Comment: oh, wow. i meant to do `if(total(p2hand) != 0 and total(p2hand)>hs):`

Comment: @JonathanK I'd just like to point out the thought process you should have used to solve this: the error is telling you that you're trying to iterate a number in `total`. The only thing you're iterating in that function is `hand`, which is the parameter of the function. That *must* mean that you're giving a number to the function when you meant a list. At that point, you should look at all the places you call `total` (or check the trace to see which call caused the error), check where the argument data is coming from that's being passed in to `total`, then figure out why it's a number.

Comment: @JonathanK As the answer shows, you wouldn't have needed to look far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 11 lines up from the bottom of your code block, you are setting the dealers hand to 0:

```
 ....
 else:
      print('Dealer went over 21!')
      dealerHand=0
```

This is concerning since their hand should be a list. Thus when you try to iterate over it to count the total, you get that an int isn't iteratable.

Should probably be something like

```
dealerHand = []
```

---

Also, a few lines after that, you are asking if `dealerHand!=0`, when I think you mean `total(dealerHand)`

---

You should also be careful with your other assignments that change a variable from a list to an int such as

```
#Around line 111
print('You went over 21!')
p1hand=0
time.sleep(1)
break
.....
#Around line 140
print('You went over 21!')
p2hand=0
time.sleep(1)
break
```

Because Python is not strongly type, changing the type of a given variable name can lead to a lot of these kinds of problems

Comment: If you feel I have answered your question, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)   =)

Comment: not until i test and confirm it works, which i am doing now

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot for your help! I will also keep what you said in mind about types.

Comment: Also, your "total" function is broken. It will total the hand 10-A-A as 22, not 12.

Comment: Yes, because this is black jack. i intended that

Comment: and sorry all, im new to the whole coding thing

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen gave you the direct answer. I suggest using pylint3 (or some other linter) on your code. It would have told you the problem

> R:170, 6: Redefinition of dealerHand type from list to int
>   (redefined-variable-type)

This will help you in the future.